# How to place navbar menu below logo?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have built this header using custom CSS and bootstrap class names. I have tried `z-index`, `float: initial` properties already. Thanks in advance

```css
.branding-preview {
    height: 75px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background-color: #0071bb;
}

.branding-logo {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
}

.branding-logo img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}

.branding-powered-by-logo {
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}

.preview-menu {
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.preview-menu > li > a {
    margin: 0 3px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: solid 1px transparent;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="branding-preview">
 <div class="branding-logo">
  <img id="branding-logo" src="/path/to/logo">
 </div>
 <div class="branding-powered-by-logo">
  <span>Powered By</span>
  <img id="branding-powered-by-logo" src="/path/to/logo" height="30">
 </div>
 <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav preview-menu">
  <li><a>Start</a></li>
  <li><a>Plan</a></li>
  <li><a>Manage</a></li>
  <li><a>Learn</a></li>
  <li><a>Admin</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This is the result that I am getting with the current code, 
actual result:

[image]

This is what I'm hoping it will look like, expected result:

[image]

Comment: Can't you just position branding logo absolute with branding preview as position relative?

Comment: Or, enclose the "powered by" and "navigation" in a single DIV element and make it float right. Let the "powered by" be text-aligned to right, and no float for both "powered by" and "navigation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't simple without all the css rules, but the concept is: Create a wrapper floated to right and inside create 2 lines, one for the `branding-powered-by-logo` and `display:block` the second line is depend from actual CSS but probably works without modify anything.

If you can post the real page we can help you with more precision.
Hope this help you.

```css
.branding-preview {
    display:block;
    height: 75px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background-color: #0071bb;
}

.branding-logo {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
}

.branding-logo img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}

.branding-powered-by-logo {
    /* ADDED */
      display:block;
      text-align:right;
    
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}

.preview-menu {
    margin: 0px 0 0 0;
}

.preview-menu > li > a {
    margin: 0 3px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: solid 1px transparent;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}


/* ADDED */
.wrapper-logo-navbar {
  float: right;
}
.preview-menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="branding-preview">
 <div class="branding-logo">
  <img id="branding-logo" src="/path/to/logo">
 </div>
  
  <div class="wrapper-logo-navbar">
    <div class="branding-powered-by-logo">
      <span>Powered By</span>
      <img id="branding-powered-by-logo" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/05/02/19/27/head-46086_960_720.png" height="30">
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav preview-menu">
      <li><a>Start</a></li>
      <li><a>Plan</a></li>
      <li><a>Manage</a></li>
      <!-- removed some elements for the rendering on StackOverflow -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need add 
`position:absolute;  right:0px;` 
to your .preview-menu class.